# Spring Web application using Java 8 does not deploy on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

The project compiles and builds fine in Java 6. Now, we are upgrading the application to Java 8. The application compiles but does not deploy in Java 8 on Tomcat 7. I see errors in the logs but I am not sure the source of the issue. Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

Here's the application context:

```
   ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName"><value>java:comp/env/jdbc/</value></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="extractor" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor" />

    <bean id="oracleLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler">
        <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor" ><ref local="extractor" /></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource"/></property>
       <property name="lobHandler"><ref local="oracleLobHandler"/></property>
       <property name="packagesToScan">
           <list>
             <value>net.core.domain</value>
             <value>net.core.domain.amounts</value>
           </list>
       </property>
       <property name="annotatedPackages">
           <list>
             <value>net.core.domain</value>
             <value>net.core.domain.amounts</value>
           </list>
       </property>
       <property name="annotatedClasses">
           <list>
             <value>neet.core.domain.CustomRevisionEntity</value>
           </list> 
       </property>       

       <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
       </property>

<!-- Envers - Auditlogging -->
        <property name="eventListeners">
          <map>
             <entry key="post-insert"><ref local="enversListener" /></entry>
             <entry key="post-update"><ref local="enversListener" /></entry>
             <entry key="post-delete"><ref local="enversListener" /></entry>
             <entry key="pre-collection-update"><ref local="enversListener" /></entry>
             <entry key="pre-collection-remove"><ref local="enversListener" /></entry>
             <entry key="post-collection-recreate"><ref local="enversListener" /></entry>
          </map>
       </property>     


    </bean>
    <bean id="enversListener" class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory"><ref local="sessionFactory" /></property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource" /></property>
```

Upon deploying it on Tomcat 7, I see the following errors in the logs:

````
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1453)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:860)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:83)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.scanPackages(AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.java:192)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.postProcessMappings(AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.java:175)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:719)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ```
````

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? For example Spring 5 is tested against Tomcat 9, but also supports Tomcat 8.5. Lower versions are not supported, and are unlikely to work.

Comment: it worked after upgrading to Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after upgrading to Tomcat 9 and changing the springframework core jar file to 4.0